# Move n characters from front of string to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

It seems like an easy problem, but i can't find solution. I want to take first, let's say 2 letters from string, and move them to the end of this string. So for example, OK12 would become 12OK.

edit: So far i've tried cutting string off, then adding it to the rest of the string, but i tought there's a one-line solution for that, like predefined function or something.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer. When a guy saying he tried, I believe him. What is the benefits of including lots of failure attempts? he probably didn't know all the string functions.

Comment: @marue. With which keywords? can you show me how?

Comment: I've used slice at first but completely ignored that fact that i could do it in one line, didn't precise that well in topic tho, sorry.

Comment: @marue. My fried, you just saw it can be tricky, and people can get confused just like it happen to you. `:)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
"OK12".substr(2) + "OK12".substr(0,2)
```

**Generic solution:**

```
var result = str.substr(num) + str.substr(0, num);
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VsYv5/1)

Comment: +1 for generic. However, regex method seems to be more neat but slower though... but more neat! :)

Comment: @VisioN. Do you really think regex is the best way here? would you say the same for matching the fourth char? `/.{3}(.)/` instead of `str[3]`? regex ins't always the best solution, and many times it's not.

Comment: @gdoron I'm not talking about that. I like regex for aesthetics mostly than for practicability.

Comment: 2022: `.substr()` is deprecated. Use `.substring()` instead

Answer (score 8):

Various techniques:

```
str.slice(2) + str.slice(0,2);

str = str.replace(/^(.{2})(.+)/, '$2$1');

for (var a=str.split(""),i=2;i--;) a.push(a.shift());
str = a.join('');
```

Comment: I liked the `regex` way, but those techniques are overkill here. By the way, why did you use `.+` and not `.*`?

Comment: @gdoron Clearly! :) But they're included for fun.

Comment: @gdoron No good reason for `.+` vs. `.*`; I suppose I assume that if you're interested in moving letters around, you expect a non-identity result ;)

Comment: +1 Yeah, the regex method is really great! Agree with @gdoron, you should better use `.*`.

Comment: @VisioN If there are exactly two characters (e.g. `"AB"`) then the `.+` will fail to match, causing the replace to do nothing, resulting in—TA DA!—`"AB"`, the correct result. Using `.+` in this case causes the interpreter to do _less_ work and still get the right result.

Comment: @Phrogz. And the array way makes me dizzy... :)

Comment: @gdoron That much spinning and looping will do that to you. ;)

Comment: @Phrogz. And <s> spitting </s> splitting. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

```
text.slice(2) + text.slice(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a='ok12';
a=a.substr(2,a.length-2)+a.substr(0,2);
```