# how can i put a period at the end of a formated text

Tags: javascript

hi this is my first question, sorry if it is stupid but i stumble upon this code

```
function format(input){
  var num = input.value.replace(/\./g,'');
  if(!isNaN(num)){
    num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{1})/g,'$1.');
    num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'');
    input.value = num;
  }

  else{ alert('just numeric values please');
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g,'');
  }
}
```

i don't really understand how it works, but basically it formats an input in real time to this format "9.9.9.9.9" but i want it to have it like this "9.9.9.9.9.". How can i add that last period?
thanks beforehand

Comment: What exactly is your goal with the function? To have a period place between every number that is entered and a period at the end?

Comment: that's right i have a number with a period on every input, but it lacks the last one. I don't know what to do. hehehe

Comment: A little more context of the problem you are trying to solve might help. That said - could you simply concatenate a "." character to the end of the output string?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is add the period to the end of the string, just do:

```
num + ".";
```

For your entire function, if you are taking a string like "12345" and just want to put a period after each number and at the end, then there are easier ways to do it than what you have:

```
text = text.replace(/(.)/g, '$1.');
```

Will do it.

Comment: man how could i be that stupid? THANK YOU VERY MUCH MAN you're a hero

Comment: What's the `slice` for? This seems to work: `'12345'.replace(/(.)/g, '$1.')`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Blurp. Removed the unneeded stuff at the end.

Comment: @Blurp well i think it is because is an input, so if try that and i type something it would simply put period after every character and it would look something like this "1.....2....3...4..5." right now i have another problem. because the function is inside of an onkeyup event it will always put a period whenever i press a key, what does this mean? well it means that if i try to delete the string on the input... unless i keep pressing the delete key the character i try to delete will never disappear

Answer (score 0):

```
input.value = num+'.';
```

or like this

```
var num = b.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'').replace(/$/, ".");
```

`/$/` means end of the string

or like this

```
var num = b.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^(.{1})(.+)/, '$2$1');
```

Take a look at this post:

[Move n characters from front of string to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841868/move-n-characters-from-front-of-string-to-the-end)

enjoy