# How do you move the first n characters of every line in a string to the end of the same line (not to end of string)?

Tags: javascript, string, substring

The string fileString contains multiple lines of characters, like this:

```
1234a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ec6df
3124a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ef248
2134a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411900b89f7dcf3
4123a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411920bbf835b60
```

I'd like to move the first 4 characters of every line to the end of its respective line, like this:

```
a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ec6df1234
a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ef2483124
a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411900b89f7dcf32134
a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411920bbf835b604123
```

I saw [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841868/move-n-characters-from-front-of-string-to-the-end) with a proposed solution, but that code moves the first 4 characters of the string to the end of the string, which is not what I'm trying to do.

So with this code:

```
var num = 4
fileString = fileString.substring(num) + fileString.substring(0, num)
```

The initial string stated above turns into this:

```
a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ec6df
3124a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ef248
2134a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411900b89f7dcf3
4123a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411920bbf835b60
1234
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No need for array manipulations**

A simple [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) using regex [capture groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences#types) seems to provide the shortest solution:

```
string.replace(/(\w{4})(\w{32})/g, '$2$1');
```

Definitions

1. `()`  = defines the capture groups
2. `\w`  = select alphanumeric characters
3. `{n}` = takes n characters
4. `$n`  = tokens representing the unnamed capture groups in sequence

And `"$2$1"` is creating a replacement string by appending the text of the first capture group to the end of the second.

For more details see: [regex101 Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/kdsgMT/1)

**Snippet**

Try the code to see how it works. You may also add brackets and spaces around the numbers and it works the same.

```js
stdout.value = stdin.value.replace(/(\w{4})(\w{32})/g, '$2$1');
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 80%;
  height: 5rem;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
Input:
<textarea id="stdin">
1234a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ec6df
3124a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ef248
2134a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411900b89f7dcf3
4123a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411920bbf835b60
</textarea>

Output:
<textarea id="stdout"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = document.querySelector('div')

  // Get the text (from wherever)
  .textContent

  // Split on the line-break
  .split('\n')

  // Filter out empty strings
  .filter(l => l.length)

  // Map over the array that `filter` returns
  // and move the characters around
  .map(str => `${str.slice(4, -4)}${str.slice(0, 4)}`)

  // Join the array up with line breaks
  .join('\n');

console.log(str);
```

```html
<div>
1234a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ec6df
3124a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ef248
2134a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411900b89f7dcf3
4123a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411920bbf835b60
</div>
```

Comment: I think you did the opposite and shifted to the right instead of left.

Comment: Ta @caTS. Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into lines and then rejoin them later:

```js
const string = `\
1234a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ec6df
3124a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0b1ef248
2134a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411900b89f7dcf3
4123a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411920bbf835b60`;

const result = string
  .split("\n")
  .map((line) => line.substring(4) + line.substring(0, 4))
  .join("\n");
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I tried this but the 4 characters are now on a new line