# How do you move n characters that are between 2 words to the end of the line (inside of a multi-line string)?

Tags: javascript, string

The multi-line string always contains XY, followed by a few characters (not always the same amount of characters), followed by :thiSWORD:

The goal is to move these few characters that are in the middle to the end of the line

So, for example, this is the original string:

```
XY1239:thiSWORD:a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0d88432f
XY545:thiSWORD:b598944d1ba4c787e411800b8043559c
XY4239:thiSWORD:a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0d8817c6
```

In the end it would look like this:

```
XY:thiSWORD:a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0d88432f1239
XY:thiSWORD:b598944d1ba4c787e411800b8043559c545
XY:thiSWORD:a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0d8817c64239
```

I have tried something along the lines of

```
str.replace(/(\w{4})(\w{48})/g, '$2$1');
```

But that only moved 4 characters, so lines that had 3 or 5 characters between XY and :thiSWORD: were messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 capture groups, and use those in the replacement:

```
XY(\d+)(.*)
```

- `XY` Match literally
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `(.*)` Capture the rest of the line in group 2

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3uyLvD/1).

```js
[
  "XY1239:thiSWORD:a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0d88432f",
  "XY545:thiSWORD:b598944d1ba4c787e411800b8043559c",
  "XY4239:thiSWORD:a6b4ba21ba54f6bde411930b0d8817c6"
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(s.replace(/XY(\d+)(.*)/, "XY$2$1"))

})
```

---

Another variant using 1 or more word characters `\w+` if there can also be word characters instead of only digits, matching 32 word chars instead of 48, word boundaries on the left and right and matching `:thiSWORD:`

```
\bXY(\w+)(:thiSWORD:\w{32})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NPDY5X/1)

Comment: This must be a homework question as I just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74331513/943435) hours ago. And it shows what can happen when people blindly copy regex without understanding what it does. Anyway, nice job +1